# How can I post a link to a Page Wall as the Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I understand the procedure (i think), you grab the page access token, then post to the /page/feed edge with 'link' and 'access_token' parameters. However, when I do this, it posts to the page as myself rather than my page and shows up under 'Posts by others'.

If I try to post a message (instead of a link) it posts fine to my Page Wall as the Page (not myself).

Just curious if anyone can confirm this to be the case? Is this how its always worked and its just not documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the page access token. If it posts as yourself instead, you did something wrong.

To get page access tokens, get it from:

```
me/accounts
```

Then, use it to post the message.

---

If you are using the Graph API Explorer, make sure you replaced the access token in this form:

[image]

and don't add `access_token=` to your query.

Comment: I just tried again through facebook graph explorer tool. I first got my page access token (via me/accounts) then i POST'ed to /mypage/feed with fields access_token and link. It went to my "Posted by others"

Comment: Thank you that worked! Was going crazy trying to figure that out.

Comment: Could you please reply if i get token this way -  FB.login(function(response) { if (response.status=='connected') {
if (response.authResponse.accessToken) { ...... } }}, {scope:'publish_stream,manage_pages' }); what this token is called page access token or user access token ?? my problem is if i post single message, post comment , post like to page wall by my this way using that token then poster name appears as page name not admin user name.